# Sub Query Confusion

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to get a understanding of how sub query's work but when I try to use a sub query does not seem to work. I tried but it comes up with errors. Pretty sure I have the right code. Any pointers of where I went wrong much appreciated.

Heres is the question I'm working on:

1. Using only a sub query, display the OrderID, OrderDate and ShippedDate for all the orders 
   submitted by employees living in the USA. Sort the output on OrderDate

Here is my sub query:

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShippedDate

FROM Orders

WHERE Country =

(SELECT Country

FROM Employees

WHERE Country = 'USA');
```

Comment: try changing country=  to country in

Comment: also you might want to try a different subquery as there is an ununcessary TABLE SCAN for yoru sub query

Comment: Does Country exist in the orders table?  If it does not, what key connects the Orders table to the Employees table?

Comment: EmployeeID are in both tables, so tried EmployeeID instead of Country but it returned results of null, which Im sure is not correct.

Comment: Maybe Im confused but wouldn't I need to use the orders table and the employees table for this question?

Comment: Could you please select some data from both the tables and include the data in the question? You can use queries like `SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 3;` and `SELECT * FROM Employees LIMIT 3;` to select 3 rows from each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShippedDate

FROM Orders

WHERE EmployeeID IN

(SELECT EmployeeID

FROM Employees

WHERE Country = 'USA');
```

In this case you are using both EmployeeID and IN.

The subquery looks for the list of EmployeeID in the USA.  Then it uses that list to select the orders made by the subset of Employees in the USA from the Orders table.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on Country when you should be joining on EmployeeID or whatever field that is, e.g. WHERE EmployeeID IN (SELECT EmployeeID ...

The way you have it matches USA to USA which will give incorrect results as any two records with USA as Country will join.